# How Key mapping works in JavaScript maps

Tags: javascript, neo4j

Below is a console.log of a result set from Neo4j. It returns an array of maps.

I'm able to `results[0].get('RESULT')`, which returns the object or map (I'm unsure which one it is) for the RESULT key.

How does this work? When I create a map, I have a key and a value but no way to have an array of keys that when I call `.get`, it returns the "mapped" object.

```
 [ Record {
     keys: [ 'RESULT', 'PROVINCE', 'CITY' ],
     length: 3,
     _fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _fieldLookup: { RESULT: 0, PROVINCE: 1, CITY: 2 }
    },
   Record {
     keys: [ 'RESULT', 'PROVINCE', 'CITY' ],
     length: 3,
     _fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _fieldLookup: { RESULT: 0, PROVINCE: 1, CITY: 2 }
    },
   Record {
     keys: [ 'RESULT', 'PROVINCE', 'CITY' ],
     length: 3,
     _fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _fieldLookup: { RESULT: 0, PROVINCE: 1, CITY: 2 }
    }]
```

When I console.log a map it looks like this:

```
Map {
    'RESULT' => { name: 'Bob' },
    'PROVINCE' => { name: 'BC' },
    'CITY' => { name: 'Nanaimo' }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the official [Neo4j Javascript Driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver).

In this case the result set you are handling is an array of [Record](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/blob/1.5/src/v1/record.js#L47) objects. When you do `results[0].get('RESULT')` you are calling the [get function](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/blob/1.5/src/v1/record.js#L93) implemented in this class.

The docs about `Record.get` function says:

> Get a value from this record, either by index or by field key.

Comment: I believe they are an array of maps since you can't use .get on an object?

Comment: @Kainan In this case `.get` is a function implemented in the class Record of Neo4j Javascript Driver. Take a look in the implementation in [this link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/blob/1.5/src/v1/record.js#L93). There is no relation with the [.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) from Map. Also, what is the output of `typeof results[0]`?

Comment: The result is Object but when I do typeof on a map it says object to. You are right on the .get being a function. Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.entries()` to get property, value pairs of the `Map` as an `Iterator` and `Array.from()` to get the properties as an array

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set("RESULT", {name:"Bob"});
map.set("PROVICE", {name:"BC"});
map.set("CITY", {name:"Nanaimo"});

let entries = Array.from(map.entries(), ([prop]) => prop);

console.log(entries);

let prop = "CITY";

console.log(
  map.get(entries[entries.indexOf(prop)])
); // `{"name": "Nanaimo"}`
```